# Using an array to pull multiple variables of data and copy to another worksheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a worksheet that I want to search for a certain criteria in column "A" and once I find the multiple variables I am looking to copy all of those particular rows that are in the array to another worksheet.  Here is the code I have, I am having trouble with it copying only the rows from the last number of the array over (seems to me like it is copying on top of each other and only keeping the last number in the array).

```
Sub Copy_Changed_Rows()

Dim Lastrow As Long

With Sheets("DataDump")

    If .Range("A:A").Find("397", , xlValues, xlWhole, , , False) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No ""Changed"" rows found. ", , "No Rows Copied": Exit Sub
    Else

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Lastrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Range("A1:A" & Lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("397", "437", "509", "646")
        .Range("A2:A" & Lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy
        Sheets("Paste").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, False, False
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        'Position on cell A3
        With Application
            .CutCopyMode = False
            .Goto Sheets("Paste").Range("A2")
            .ScreenUpdating = True
        End With

        MsgBox "All matching data has been copied.", , "Copy Complete"

    End If

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What I found was there was one piece missing on the filter at the end of the filter line add `, Operator:=xlFilterValues`

```
Sub Copy_Changed_Rows()

Dim Lastrow As Long

With Sheets("DataDump")

    If .Range("A:A").Find("397", , xlValues, xlWhole, , , False) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No ""Changed"" rows found. ", , "No Rows Copied": Exit Sub
    Else

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Lastrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Range("A1:A" & Lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("397", "437", "509", "646"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

        .Range("A2:A" & Lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy
        Sheets("Paste").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, False, False
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        'Position on cell A3
        With Application
            .CutCopyMode = False
            .Goto Sheets("Paste").Range("A2")
            .ScreenUpdating = True
        End With

        MsgBox "All matching data has been copied.", , "Copy Complete"

    End If

End With
```